# How to show that a large given integer isn't a square number by using mod?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Given a big integer like $4531893869$ the question is how to show that this number isn't a square number using mod $11$.

Basically what we have is something like that:
$$ 4531893869 \equiv x \pmod{11}$$
and we know that $ x \in \{1\ldots10\}$.

According to Wolfram Alpha the result is $8$.

But I don't understand how this will show us that this large number isn't a square number. I have to explicitly use mod $11$ to solve this task but I don't understand the mathematical context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hint. The squares modulo 11 are $0,1,4,9,5,3$. Since $10^k\equiv (-1)^k \pmod{11}$ it follows that the number $4531893869$ modulo $11$ can be obtained by computing:
$$-4+5-3+1-8+9-3+8-6+9\pmod{11}.$$
If it does not belong to $\{0,1,4,9,5,3\}$ then $4531893869$ can not be a square modulo 11 and therefore it is not a perfect square.

Comment: How do I find out that the squares modulo 11 are 0,1,4,9,5,3?

Comment: Just compute $j^2\pmod{11}$ for $j=0,\dots, 10$. Actually $j=0,\dots, 5$ is enough because $j^2\equiv (11-j)^2\pmod{11}$.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot. The alternating sum is the key point here

Comment: Yes. Note that in this case you could replace 11 by 3. $4531893869\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ (here you consider the sum of the digits since $10\equiv 1\pmod{3}$) and $2$ is not a square modulo 3.

Comment: You could also use modulus 8.Then you'd only have to look at the last three digits.

Comment: I don't understand this alternating sum. With 1 = -1(good). 4 = -4 (good). 9 = -9(good). 16 = -1+6 = 5 (good). 25 = -2+5=3(good). 36 = -3+6=3(good). 49 = -4+9 = 5 (good). 64 = -6+4=-2 (huh?). 81 = -8+1 = -7(what?)

Comment: @dberm22 Firstly, your signs are wrong as $10^k \equiv (-1)^k \mod 11$: if it helps, start from the end where $10^0 = 1$ (thus for example $144 \equiv 4 - 4 + 1 \equiv 1 \mod 11$, not $-1 + 4 - 4 \equiv -1$). Secondly, modulo $11$, we have $-2 \equiv 9$, and $-7 \equiv 4$, so $64 \equiv -2 \equiv 9$ and $81 \equiv -7 \equiv 4$ are indeed squares.

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed a step, but can you say all square numbers mod 11 will result in one of those results?

Comment: @SGR Yes, all the squares modulo $11$ are given by  $j^2 \pmod{11}$ for $j=0,\dots,5$.

Answer (score 7):

The key point is that not every value mod $11$ can be a square. In fact for any square $n^2$, $n$ must be congruent to one of $0,1,...,10$ mod $11$, and so $n^2$ must be congruent to one of $0^2,1^2,...,10^2$ mod $11$. So as long as none of $0^2,1^2,...,10^2$ is congruent to $8$ mod $11$, there are no squares congruent to $8$ mod $11$, and your number can't be square.

In fact you can save yourself some work here: $10\equiv -1$ mod $11$, so $10^2\equiv(-1)^2=1^2$, so once you've checked $1^2$ you don't need to check $10^2$. Similarly with other pairs of numbers which have sum $11$, so in fact it is sufficient to check none of $0^2,1^2,...,5^2$ is congruent to $8$ mod $11$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ n^{\large 2}\equiv 2^{\large 3}\equiv x\ $ when raised to $\color{#c00}5$'th power contradicts little Fermat, viz.

$\quad\overset{(\ \ \ )^{\Large\color{#c00} 5}}\Longrightarrow\,\ \underbrace{ 1\equiv (n^{\large 2})^{\large\color{#c00} 5}}_{\rm Fermat}\!\equiv  (2^{\large 3})^{\large\color{#c00} 5}\equiv (2^{\large 5})^{\large 3}\equiv (-1)^{\large 3}\equiv -1,\ $ but $\,\  1\not\equiv -1\pmod{\!11}$

**Remark** $ $ This method of square testing works generally - see [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). It is much more efficient than brute-force enumerative tests for larger numbers.

Generally we can disprove equalities of integer arithmetical expressions by checking that they are not congruent modulo $m$. This works because modular reduction is compatible with addition and multiplication (see the [Congruence Sum and Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)), so it preserves equalities (as congruences) between integer expressions composed of sums and products, i.e. *polynomial* expressions of integers, e.g.  $$ P(i,j,k) = Q(i,j,k) \ \Rightarrow\ P(i,j,k)\equiv Q(i,j,k)\pmod m$$

for any polynomials $P,Q$ with integer coefficients. So if the congruence fails for some modulus $m$ then the LHS equality must also fail.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this is complete overkill for a problem as rudimentary as this, but another method to tell if $4531893869$ is quadratic residue$\pmod{11}$ is to use the Legendre symbol: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

$\begin{align} \left( 4531893869 / 11 \right) & \equiv 4531893869^{\frac{11-1}{2}}\pmod {11} \\ & \equiv 8^{\frac{11-1}{2}} \\& \equiv -1 \end{align}$

So, no.  It is not.

I only suggest this because I enjoyed learning about this and quadratic reciprocity immensely in undergrad.  :)

Comment: This is Euler's Criterion. This method was already mentioned in my answer a month prior. Please don't duplicate prior answers.